# How to override a specific environment variable during ReactJS build?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm having a bit of difficulty navigating the rigid `NODE_ENV` mechanism on NodeJS and React.

During the build of my application, an important environment-specific value is obtained and available to the build scripts.

The value is available when executing `npm ci` and `npm run build` and deploying the bundle to a static S3 bucket (SPA style) which happens in the build script.

I would like to set a variable, API_URL to the proper value during the build.

However, NodeJS or React seems to enforce the idea of only a single variable (`NODE_ENV`) with 3 possible values ("development", "test", "production") and `if` statements in the code. This is not practical in my case because the value is not known during coding; it materializes during the build script. i.e. I cannot write the `if`-statements ahead of time.

How can I explicitly set an arbitrary environment variable to the value I want, during the build, and access its value in the ReactJS application?

Comment: Are you using Create React App or Vite (or something else)? Both have requirements on naming environment variables that are made available to your front-end code

Comment: Create-react-app. I already found out about the REACT_APP_ prefix and that seemed to work fine locally. Current latest obstacle is that the `.env` file seems to be completely ignored in the ci build process, and only works locally.

Comment: Is the `.env` file included in your version control (assuming CI does a clean checkout)? You should also be able to set regular environment variables (ie not in `.env`) that will be picked up by the build process... `REACT_APP_API_URL=https://example.com npm run build`

Comment: Yes, I was able to verify that the file and expected contents are present during the CI build. I will try the latter approach of setting the value in the CLI.

Comment: Doesn't need to be a command prefix, just present. Most CI systems let you set env vars

Comment: Somehow, both approaches are working now. I think there was a cache refresh issue somewhere between my browser, Cloud Front, S3, and the build artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to prefix the variables with `REACT_APP_`, and then use either the `.env` file or an override in the CLI for `npm run build`.

When making changes, be sure to restart processes and clear caches.